# Hydrogen traceback error in Atom running Python 3.9.1 on Mac OS 11.0.1

Tags: python-3.x, atom-editor, jupyter-lab, hydrogen

I do not use conda or pyenv's. I am getting a traceback error for few days now that's unable to execute Hydrogen in Atom:

```
> Python 3 
>> Traceback (most recent call last): File
>> "/usr/local/Cellar/python@3.9/3.9.1_1/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/runpy.py",
>> line 197, in _run_module_as_main
```

I am executing from a homebrewed python 3.9.1 located at:

```
> /usr/local/opt/python@3.9/bin/python3.9
```

The executable from the terminal and from inside Atom are identical.

Jupyter Labs is running fine. The output of jupyter --paths:

```
> config:
>>     /Users/kylereaves/.jupyter
>>     /usr/local/Cellar/python@3.9/3.9.1_1/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/etc/jupyter
>>     /usr/local/etc/jupyter
>>     /etc/jupyter 
> data:
>>     /Users/kylereaves/Library/Jupyter
>>     /usr/local/Cellar/python@3.9/3.9.1_1/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/share/jupyter
>>     /usr/local/share/jupyter
>>     /usr/share/jupyter 
> runtime:
>>     /Users/kylereaves/Library/Jupyter/runtime

The output of jupyter kernelspec list:
>> Available kernels:   python3  /Users/kylereaves/Library/Jupyter/kernels/python3
```

I have no idea what happened to break Hydrogen. Everything's current.

Answer (score 0):

I uninstalled ipykernel and than reinstalled it according to https://nteract.io/kernels.
In a new .py file, I imported sys and printed out the version. [image] I am still very confused.But it's working again, so that's nice.

Comment: appreciate your solution but it did not work for me. still need solution to this problem.

Comment: Looking deeper, it both did and did not work for me. This is so weird: So following the uninstall, reinstall, it worked in a new file. reopening the original folder in Atom, i still have the same problem as above. Unsure why Atom Hydrogen can execute in the new file, but not in a previous project.